# Trying to learn Reactjs by making a weather app but i'm stuck at "TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to Reactjs and i try to learn by building something easy but i'm stuck at this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined" when i try to render the data fetched from openweathermap and i really don't know what i am doing wrong.

Any help please?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import Weather from "./Weather"
import Loading from "./Loading"


 const App = () =>{
        const [data, setData] = useState([]);
        const [text, setText] = useState("");
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const submitHandler = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(loading){
        return <Loading />
    }
}

const fetchWeather = async () =>{
    try {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${text}&appid=4d8fb5b93d4af21d66a2948710284366&units=metric`);
        const weather = await response.json();
        setData(weather);
        console.log(data); 
        setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

useEffect(() =>{
    fetchWeather();
}, [text]);


return (
    <section>
        <form type="submit"  className="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e) =>setText(e.target.value)} />
            <button type="submit" className="btn">Search</button>
        </form>
        <Weather data={data} />
    </section>
);
```

}

**Weather component**

```
import React from "react"

const Weather = ({data}) =>{
return (
  <div>
    { (data !== "undefined") ? (
      <section className="weather">
      <div className="title">
        <h2>{data.name}</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="today">
        <div className="info">
          <h3>{Math.floor(data.main.temp)} C</h3>
          <p>{data.weather[0].description}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="icon">
        
        </div>
      </div>
   </section>
    ) : ("")}
  </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Please add full code for both components seems that the first code snippet is not fully added

Comment: From the error message it looks like data has no “main” property. Are you sure you are accessing it the right way? Is data an object? Maybe you should call response.body.json() instead, and then parse it to obtain a JavaScript object.

Comment: `data !== "undefined"` will only give you `false` if `data` is actually a string containing the word 'undefined' try `data!=null` instead

Comment: Tried with null instead of "undefined" and it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<section>
   <form type="submit"  className="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />            <button type="submit" className="btn">Search</button>
   </form>
   {data ? <Weather data={data} />: null}
</section>
```

);

Comment: the error says "temp" of undefined means main is undefined inside weather so try this
   {data.length > 0 ? <Weather data={data} />: null}

Comment: This solves the error message but now Weather component doesn't appear when i search for a city

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by doing this in Weather component after some more google search.Thanks to all who responded and helped me with this.

Is this a good solution for future projects if i will have the same error?

```
import React from "react"


const Weather = ({data}) =>{
  console.log(data);
    return (
      <div>
        {(data.main && data.sys && data.weather) ? (
          <section className="weather">
          <div className="title">
            <h2>{data.name}</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="today">
            <div className="info">
              <h3>{Math.floor(data.main.temp)} C</h3>
              <p>{data.weather[0].description}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="icon">
            
            </div>
          </div>
       </section>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
}
```